# java - downloading a input stream using servlets

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am using the following code to get the content from an object in s3 bucket. I am able to copy the data into a file locally, but the file needs to be 'downloaded' and it has to be shown in the browser's downloads list.
I searched a bit about this and cam to know this has something to do with   `response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"" );`
I tried to add that too but somehow couldn't get it to work. My understanding is that the source has to be a file on a server which is converted into a stream. but I get the s3 contents in the form of a input stream. How to i download this as a file in the browser?
Below is the code i have tried so far

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());    
S3Object fetchFile = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketname, fileloc));
        final BufferedInputStream i = new BufferedInputStream(fetchFile.getObjectContent());
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"" );            
        ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
        int bytesread = i.read();
        while(bytesread!=-1)
        {
            sos.write(bytesread);
            bytesread = i.read();
        }
        if(i!= null)i.close();
        if(sos!= null)sos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except the file reading part.

```
//Set the size of buffer to stream the data.
  byte []buffer=new byte[1024*8];
```

instead of

```
  int byte=i.read();
```

Now read the file.

```
  while( ( length = yourInputStream.read(buffer))!=-1)
    {       yourOutputStream.write(buffer); 
                }
    System.out.println("File is downloaded.");
```

Additionally,puting your whole code within **try/catch** block will help you to know the exact reason of your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks! but this did not make any difference and neither did i get any exception

Comment: Hi, any other insights please? I am still stuck on this one :(